# How to account for spaces in a python vigenere chiper

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher, vigenere

Hi I'm writing a vigenere cipher program for a class in python it has to be able to handle upper case, lower cases, and other random characters, the other random characters however will be ignored and not encrypted example below

> python vigenere.py -e "This is my key"
>
> hello world
>
> altdw oapvh
>
> This is my message that I am sending you!
>
> Moqk qk yw wiqlhow bzmr S ek llvvqfs wyy!

my current problem is in both the encryption and decryption is I dont know how to get the cipher to shift so the next key while passing the message through, the code for the encryption function is

```
#encrypt a plantext string
def encrypt(message, key):                                                                                   
# single letter encrpytion.                                                                
def enc(c,k):
    #checks to see if the character is a letter or another character
    if(not(c.isalpha())):
        return c
    else:
        #the actual encryption algorithm see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher algebraeic description
        return chr((((ord(k) - 65) + (ord(c) - case(c))) % 26) + case(c))                              

#add single letters back together
return "".join(starmap(enc, zip(message, cycle(key))))
```

if anyone has an easy way to do this and keep all spaces and ! without changing how the chiper should work please let me know!

Comment: So, to rephrase, you don't want the character of the key to be skipped unless it is actually *used* to encrypt something, right?